# Real roots of a non linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine the number of real roots of the equation-

$$x^2+10x+(\sin(x))^2=\cos(x)$$

> How to solve such kind of questions? Please suggest some reference also.

Comment: Don't write it $((\sin(x))^2$ but $\sin^2x$

Comment: @SufyanNaeem why?  I think $(\sin x)^2$ is much better notation.

Comment: Richard Feynman kept thinking same. But later, in his future, he found problems with using his own notations and so he moved toward the standard.

Comment: What level of mathematics are you looking for? This problem is quite easy using first-year calculus: does that suffice?

Comment: @Rory are u suggesting for using Newton Raphson?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem $(\sin x)^2$ is completely standard math notation, albeit less commonly written than $\sin^2 x$.  What Feynman did was not at all the same.

Comment: No, just look at the derivative and the two roots (near $0$ and $-10$). The derivative is usually very large and must be increasing or decreasing in certain intervals. There are only two roots. Do you want details?

Comment: It is worth noting that the zeros of this equation [must be transcendental](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193047/can-we-subtract-a-trigonometric-term-from-a-polynomial/1193125#1193125). Further, they cannot be expressed in closed form, so you can find your roots only in approximate form.

Comment: @RoryDaulton a detail will be much helpful..

Comment: Write this as polynomial expression = trigonometric expression. Sketch the polynomial. You can also sketch the trigonometric expression and get some idea what is going on - you can identify that the trigonometric part has a small range of values and reduce the region you need to explore.

Comment: My calculator program (TI-Nspire Teacher Software) cannot use $\sin^2x$ but must use $(sin(x))^2$, as you see in the graphic in my answer. Does that settle the notation issue? ... No?

Answer (score 1):

**You can write $\sin^2(x)$ if you don't want to confuse with $\sin(x)^2$**

---

You only need the number of solutions? Let's start with some analityc math:

> We have  $x^2+10x+(\sin(x))^2=\cos(x)$, then since $(\sin(x))^2=1-(\cos(x))^2$: 
>   $$x^2+10x+1=\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)$$ 
>   Now let $f(x)=x^2+10x+1$ and $g(x)=\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)$, if we draw this two functions (this is not hard, $g(x)$ is an even function, and $f(x)$ is a parabola)
>   [image]

You can see that are $2$ solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't trust a graphical solution for this... it might give you some intuition, and maybe some starting points if you're looking for approximate solutions, but you should really verify this analitically.

Comment: that is because i'm asking if he only needs the number of solutions, Intuition wins in this case because the polynomial grows and never comeback close to $X$ axis and the other function always take lower values. But if we want the real solutions we must do it analitically. Or use the IVT

Comment: You didn't understand my point. I mean that this argument shows that there are at least $2$ solutions and that likely there are no more, but you must *prove* it analytically. I never said that you *were* looking for approximate solutions.

Comment: oh sorry, english is not my native language and i'm bad at english. you're right. this don't work always and is necesary a proof. e.g spaces of dimension $>3$

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Taking all terms to the left hand side, your function is between the parabolas $x^2+10x+2$ and $x^2+10x-2$. Those parabolas show that there are only two possible places for a root: between $-11$ and $-9$ and between $0$ and $1$. A look at the derivative shows that there can be only one root in each of those intervals. Therefore, there are exactly two roots.

[image]

**Details:**

The roots of your equation are the same as those of

$$f(x)=x^2+10x+\sin^2 x-\cos x=0$$

Note that the trigonometric part of the function, $\sin^2 x-\cos x$, has two parts which each are between $-1$ and $1$. Therefore that trig part must be between $-2$ and $2$.

We quickly see that $f(0)=-1$. Using the last paragraph, $f(1)\ge 1^2+10(1)-2=10$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, there is a root for $0<x<1$.

Also, $f(-11)\ge (-11)^2+10(-11)-2=130$, and $f(-9)\le (-9)^2+10(-9)+2=-7$. There is also a root of $f(x)$ for $-11<x<-9$.

For later use, note that $f(-6)\le (-6)^2+10(-6)+2=-22$ and $f(-4)\le (-4)^2+10(-4)+2=-22$. Also note that the vertex of the parabola $x^2+10x$ is at $x=-5$ at is at a minimum, so $f(x)\le -22$ for $-6\le x\le -4$.

Now look at the derivative,

$$f'(x)=2x+10+2\sin x \cos x+\sin x=2x+10+\sin 2x+\sin x$$

The trigonometric part of $f'(x)$ must be between $-2$ and $2$. Therefore, for $x<-6$, $f'(x)<2(-6)+10+2=0$, and for $x>-4$, $f'(x)>2(-4)+10-2=0$.

Now put this all together.

For $x<-6$, $f'(x)<0$ so $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing there. There can be at most one root there. We have seen there is a root there, between $-11$ and $-9$, so there is exactly one root there.

For $-6\le x\le -4$, $f(x)\le -22$, so there is no root there.

For $-4<x$, $f'(x)>0$ so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing there. There can be at most one root there. We have seen there is a root there, between $0$ and $1$, so there is exactly one root there.

This covers all real numbers, so $f(x)$ has exactly two roots. The presentation above is a proof of this. As another answer showed, graphing and intuition show it more easily, but the trig part of the function made a proof longer than we would like.